# NSDictionary with swift

Tags: ios, swift

**Test dictionary declaration:**

```
var data = [
            "A": [["userid":"1","username":"AAA","usergroupid":"2"], ["userid":"33","username":"ABB","usergroupid":"8"]],
            "B": [["userid":"2","username":"BBB","usergroupid":"8"], ["userid":"43","username":"ABC","usergroupid":"8"]]
           ]
```

How do I get the following output ?

**For example:** 
 A -> username AAA , ABB
 B -> username BBB , ABC

Comment: Go to "Dictionaries". The documentation uses examples and everything :)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: Also that really isn't an NSDictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for group in data {
    let userNames = group.1.reduce("username ", combine: { (current, userInfo) -> String in
        return "\(current), \(userInfo["username"]!)"
    })

    print("\(group.0) \(userNames)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have one more question, A: username AAA userid 1 , username ABB userid 2 How do we do it

Comment: @pirpirim Ask a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

Key-Value-Coding is your friend:

```
let usernamesA = (data["A"]! as NSArray).valueForKey("username")
let usernamesB = (data["B"]! as NSArray).valueForKey("username")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have one more question,
A: username AAA userid 1 , username ABB userid 2

How do we do it

Comment: That's beyond the skills off KVC

Comment: so we have to use what method ?

Comment: What kind of collection type do you expect?

Comment: @pirpirim I included a solution to yield output `A: username: AAA userid: 1, username: ABB userid: 33` in my answer below (assuming you are in fact using a `NSDictionary`?).

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with an `NSDictionary`, an alternative to KVC method `.valueForKey` is `.valueForKeyPath`, useful when wanting to enter nested values in an `NSDictionary`.

```
let foo : (NSDictionary, String) -> (String?) = { 
    ($0.valueForKeyPath($1+".username") as? NSArray)?.reduce($1+" ->") {$0+" "+($1 as! String)}
}

print(foo(data, "A") ?? "Key not found") // A -> AAA ABB
print(foo(data, "B") ?? "Key not found") // B -> BBB ABC
print(foo(data, "C") ?? "Key not found") // Key not found
```

Using `data`:

```
var data : NSDictionary = [
    "A": [["userid":"1","username":"AAA","usergroupid":"2"], ["userid":"33","username":"ABB","usergroupid":"8"]],
    "B": [["userid":"2","username":"BBB","usergroupid":"8"], ["userid":"43","username":"ABC","usergroupid":"8"]]
]
```

---

To answer your additional question

> To vadian:s answer, you wrote:
>
> *"Thank you for the answer, I have one more question,*
>
> ```
> A: username AAA userid 1 , username ABB userid 2
> ```
>
> "

You can solve this e.g. making use of `zip` combined with the `.valueForKeyPath` KVC-technique used above. One solution follows below

```
let bar : (NSDictionary, String) -> (String?) = {
    dict, key in
    guard let 
        uName = ((dict.valueForKeyPath(key+".username") as? NSArray)?.map { String($0) }),
        uId = ((dict.valueForKeyPath(key+".userid") as? NSArray)?.map { String($0) }) else {
        return nil
    }
    var foo = Array(zip(uName,uId)).reduce(key+": ") { $0 + "username: " + $1.0 + " userid: " + $1.1 + ", " }
    foo.removeRange(foo.endIndex.advancedBy(-2)..<foo.endIndex)
    return foo
}

print(bar(data, "A") ?? "Key not found")
    // A: username: AAA userid: 1, username: ABB userid: 33
print(bar(data, "B") ?? "Key not found")
    // B: username: BBB userid: 2, username: ABC userid: 43
print(bar(data, "C") ?? "Key not found")
    // Key not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation on dictionaries in Swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) under "Dictionaries".

So for this Dictionary:

```
var data = [
        "A": [["userid":"1","username":"AAA","usergroupid":"2"], ["userid":"33","username":"ABB","usergroupid":"8"]],
        "B": [["userid":"2","username":"BBB","usergroupid":"8"], ["userid":"43","username":"ABC","usergroupid":"8"]]
       ]
```

If you want to get the value `[["userid":"1","username":"AAA","usergroupid":"2"]` you would do this:

```
data["A"]
```

If you want to access the value for the key `username` you would do this.

```
data["A"]!["username"] //which equals "AAA"
```